# the apple id you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. please try again trying to test the In app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am Integrating IAP in my ios game for removing ads. After done all the coding and integration, I tried to test the IAP, But whenever i click the ad removal button it ask me to login to apple store after I type all my login credentials it is showing error on my Ipad. I am testing with my test user account only, still it is showing this error. Any help over this will be thankful.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't delete the account in iTunes Connect?

Comment: No i didn't delete my account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create your test user account in sandbox environment, or else it wont accept your test account or your personal account so create the test user account in sandbox mode. To do this first sign in to Itunes connect and in the home page select Sandbox Testers to create a new sandbox tester Id to test your app.

Note:  To create a sandbox test user account you should have admin Tecnical role of your account. For more details follow this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW9

Comment: In the redesigned iTunes Connect there's now a "Sandbox Testers" tab at the top of the Users and Roles page. Accounts created using the first tab - even if they have the "In-App Purchase" credential, do not work with the sandbox.

Comment: Does this take a certain amount of time to register or does it work instantly?